# Multiple Google Gauges with different option sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm trying to insert multiple instances of Google Gauges (or Highchart Gauges) on a page.
I want to use different option sets and place them apart. So I cannot use the solution presented here, I think: [Google Charts multiple gauges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475431/google-charts-multiple-gauges)

I've given it an attempt here: http://jsfiddle.net/tcmsu475/1/

I'm missing something fundamental. It's the same with Highchart charts. I cannot seem to draw 1 chart in 1 div and then another in another div.

The code (for future reference):

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1','packages':['gauge']}]}"></script>
<div id="chart1_div" />
<div id="chart2_div" />
...

$(function () {

    var chart1_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Band1', 100], ]);

    var options1 = {
        width: 500,
        height: 120,
        redFrom: 75,
        redTo: 100,
        yellowFrom: 25,
        yellowTo: 75,
        greenFrom: 0,
        greenTo: 25,
        minorTicks: 5,
        greenColor: '#CCFFCC',
        yellowColor: '#FFFFCC',
        redColor: '#F78181'
    };

    var chart1 = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart1_div'));

    chart1.draw(chart1_data, options1);

    /* ========================================================= */

    var chart2_data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Label', 'Value'],
        ['Band2', 50], ]);

    var options2 = {
        width: 500,
        height: 120,
        redFrom: 90,
        redTo: 100,
        yellowFrom: 50,
        yellowTo: 90,
        greenFrom: 0,
        greenTo: 50,
        minorTicks: 5,
        greenColor: '#CCFFCC',
        yellowColor: '#FFFFCC',
        redColor: '#F78181'
    };

    var chart2 = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart2_div'));

    chart2.draw(chart2_data, options2);

});
...
```

Comment: You can certainly do this with Highcharts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define your divs differently and it just works:

```
<div id="chart1_div"></div>
<div id="chart2_div"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lgahj01z/

Comment: Excellent! (Damn html language!)